# Correct use of Pronoun

Tags: grammaticality

Consider the following sentences-

1- He is taller than me.

2- He is taller than i am.

Which one is grammatically correct and acceptable in various English language exams?

(I've read about it in some books.. Asked some teachers but still there is confusion)

Comment: Strictly speaking, (2) is correct, but (1) is widely used in colloquial speech.

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/44188/99 https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/11102/99 Good Luck